# ValueError: could not convert integer scalar in scipy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

During a NLP process, I transform a corpus of texts using TF-IDF which yields a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`.

I then split this data into train and test corpus and resample my train corpus in order to tackle a class imbalance problem.

The issue I'm facing is that when I use the resampled index (from the label which is of type `pandas.Series`) to resample the sparse matrix like this:

```
tfs[Ytr_resample.index]
```

It takes a lot of time, and outputs the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-dd1413907d77> in <module>()
----> 1 tfs[Ytr_cat_resample.index]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    348         csr_sample_values(self.shape[0], self.shape[1],
    349                           self.indptr, self.indices, self.data,
--> 350                           num_samples, row.ravel(), col.ravel(), val)
    351         if row.ndim == 1:
    352             # row and col are 1d

ValueError: could not convert integer scalar
```

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168699/cryptic-scipy-could-not-convert-integer-scalar-error) I checked that the biggest element in the index wouldn't be bigger than the number of rows in my sparse matrix.

The problem seems to come from the fact that the index is coded in `np.int64` and not in `np.int32`. Indeed the following works:

```
Xtr_resample = tfs[[np.int32(ind) for ind in Ytr_resample.index]]
```

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is the error actually coming from this conversion `int32` to `int64`?
2. Is there a more pythonic way to convert the index type? (`Ytr_resample.index.astype(np.int32)` does not seem to change the type for some reason)

EDIT:

`Ytr_resample.index` is of type `pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index`:

```
Int64Index([1484,  753, 1587, 1494,  357, 1484,   84,  823,  424,  424,
        ...
        1558, 1619, 1317, 1635,  537, 1206, 1152, 1635, 1206,  131],
       dtype='int64', length=4840)
```

I created `Ytr_resample` by resampling `Ytr` (which is `pandas.Series`) such that every category present in `Ytr` has the same number of elements (by oversampling):

```
n_samples = Ytr.value_counts(dropna = False).max()
Ytr_resample = pd.DataFrame(Ytr).groupby('cat').apply(\
                                lambda x: x.sample(n_samples,replace = True,random_state=42)).cat
```

Comment: Tell us more about `Ytr_resample.index`.  dtype, shape etc.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited my question to add the type and shape of `Ytr_resample.index` as long as the piece of code I use to produce it. Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't know `pandas` very well, but that `values` is widely used to extract arrays from pandas objects,  e.g. `Ytr_resample.index.values`.

Comment: It's a good idea, I tried this and it works. Although I expected some performance gain compared to redifining element by element the index into `int32`. Weirdly, it gives the exact same computation time (I tested using `timeit`).